# How to take allure from S3?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, allure

I want to save and use the allure report from amazon S3 (not in-home workspace), so used S3 publisher plugin

`target/allure-results` and `allure-report` folders with files were published into amazon S3, but I can't take allure form S3

How I can do that?

Comment: Are you trying to use the history from previous test runs to include in your allure report?

Comment: @braebdeb I wanna take the results of the previous test and see it like in allure report if it's possible from AWS S3. Or some other ways to see results from S3. The main idea was the saving allure report in S3 and use it in Jenkins

Comment: May possible to read the completed allure report from S3 and include it in Jenkins frore view?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to enable public access to your Allure reports from within S3, you can follow the [official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html). In this case, a custom domain name is used. However, you can do the same w/o it just by enabling website hosting and relaxing bucket restrictions.

Note that it's not a secured way to access your reports, as they become visible to the outside world. Even if you use a CloudFront to restrict access to your bucket, it won't solve the visibility problem. It's a critical security issue, as you usually expose different URLs and credentials in test reports.

On one of my projects, there was a GitLab, and we created a simple html page with links to build logs and Allure / Swagger coverage reports. This page was registered to a customer's subdomain and accessible by authorized GitLab users only. Everything else (results aggregation, report generation, copying history, etc.) was handled from within GitLab pipeline.

I'd recommend talking to your DevOps and explain what you are trying to achieve considering all the security concerns. It's basically a one-day job for them.